# Testing kafka application using localstack

Tags: apache-kafka, localstack

I want to test my application that is using kafka through localstack.

But can not see the support for kakfa. It used to have the kafka support.

Is localstack support kafka?

If yes, at which port does it run?

Answer (score 1):

[Localstack](https://github.com/localstack/localstack) is

> A fully functional local AWS cloud stack. Develop and test your cloud & Serverless apps offline!

So, it's about AWS. Localstack does not support Kafka and never supported it.

Did you mean Kinesis instead?